# How can I count number of distinct rows of a table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tried:

```
select count(distinct *) from table_name;
```

but it's wrong. And there's no column that has been defined as unique in my table.

Comment: I think this query is least of your problems. I think your database design is the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a sub-select to filter down to no duplicates, and then count that.

```
select count(*)
from (select distinct * from table_name
     ) t
```

I would concur that the table-design may have problems if it has no PK.

Answer (score 0):

You could list all your columns in the `distinct` clause:

```
SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT col1, col2, etc)
FROM   table_name
```